# the book was in the desk drawer

Tags: meaning, word-usage

a. I guessed the book was in the desk drawer.

b. I guessed the book would be in the desk drawer.

Do either of these sentences indicate that I was right?

Do either of them indicate that I was wrong?

Is there any way to use the verb 'guess' in similar sentences in such a way as to show that the guess was correct?

My impression is that (a) tends to imply that I was correct, but it is not really certain.

Many thanks

Comment: Neither suggests that you were right or wrong. You could say 'I _correctly_ or _wrongly_ guessed that the book was/would be in the drawer'.

Comment: The word ***guess*** normally implies uncertainty - you could strengthen the implication of being correct with *I **surmised / deduced** that the book **was** there* (where ***would be** there* would weaken the "confidence level"). Or just force the implication with *I **realised** that it was there*.